# Delete files copied to Forms directory

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have incorrectly copied some files into the Forms directory in the root of a Document Library. I do not seem to be able to delete these files using file explorer and they are not visible on the SharePoint site.

How do I delete these extra files and leave just the SharePoint files? I do have a full list of the files to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Open the site in SharePoint designer to find the Forms library, then delete files in it:
[image]

Or show the hidden items in file explorer as shown below:
[image]

[image]